# "@sessions" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter, omniauth

I am using https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter

Apparently this issue only happens on the iPhone and iPad.

Here's how to replicate the issue. I tweeted on Twitter. The tweet contains a link that points to by web app: https://www.foobar.com/1 (ps This is a dummy link. You can use your own link).

Make sure the controller/method handling the link (https://www.foobar.com/1) has the following line `redirect_to "/auth/twitter?use_authorize=true"`

On the iPhone or iPad, open up the Twitter App. Search for the tweet. Tap on the link (https://www.foobar.com/1).

The page should redirect you back to `/auth/twitter?use_authorize=true`. Everything works fine so far. The user is sent to Twitter's login portal/form. However, after the user fills out the form and submits it. Instead, of being redirected back to our web app, he is sent to Twitter where it says:

```
"@sessions" does not exist
```

Anyone else experience this before? At this point, I don't know if this is a Twitter API issue or the way I am supposed to redirect with the gem.

The issue also seems apparent with other people:

- https://twitter.com/Starbucks/status/482656278410723328
- https://twitter.com/CocaCola/status/483420891393826816
- https://twitter.com/RayaVlogs/status/492528237629943808
- https://twitter.com/MattNavarraUK/status/494915033634447360
- https://twitter.com/WillHillBet/status/497021431021330433

**Update:** Searching @sessions on Twitter, returns several people experiencing the same issue. It may be related to Twitter's API, more than anything. Apparently, its also happening with their widgets. Anyone think of a workaround?